# Array with a lot of depth seems to break PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' on line 92. However, when I change `implode()` to `""`, everything magically worked again.

This is my code:

```
  $arrayThings = array(
      other entries...      
      "border" => array(
            "category" => "bgBorders",
            "verify" => array("func" => "verifyBool", "error" => "errormessage"),
            "type" => XenForo_Input::UINT,
            "permission" => "canUseBorderIn%sM",
            "format" => array(
                "span" => array(
                    "attr" => array(
                        "style" => array(
                            "border" => implode(" ", self::$borderDefaults), // L92
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
        ),
        ....other entries
   )
```

I have hand-verified other entries' syntax to be correct. I'm using PHP 5.4.15. Does anybody know the problem?

Comment: what was the 92nd line?

Comment: @KevinPaladin `L92` marked one, I suppose.

Comment: It works with `PHP 5.4.14`. commented out `"type" => XenForo_Input::UINT`, replaced `self::$borderDefaults` with `array(1,2,3)`. It is working.

Comment: Is this a property definition within a class?

Comment: @MarkBaker The array itself is in a class, yes.

Comment: @CORRUPT XenForo_Input::UINT is defined, and other entries uses it without issues.

Comment: In method definition, or class body? You can not evaluate / call function in class body definition.

Comment: @CORRUPT Class body. Declared as `public static`.

Comment: If it's the property definition, then you can't use `run-time information`... the output from `implode` is `run-time information`

Comment: @MarkBaker I see, that's probably my problem.

Comment: @MarkBaker I suppose you can't do self:: either?

Comment: You can not use anything, that requires evaluation. Constants are allowed. Scalar values are allowed (arrays included). Variables and functions - not allowed.